# python sklearn.decomposition FactorAnalysis functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I am running a factor analysis on my stock returns matrix (200*676) using sklearn.decomposition FactorAnalysis and I have three functions : fit, transform and transform_fit, which one should 
I used to get the factor loadings?

Answer (score 0):

I guess is the `components_` is the factor loadings. I only applied this algorithm in R before. I am not sure it is the loadings in Python. As a check, the loading should satisfy the equation `Cov = LL^T + Sigma`. In python, it is

```
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis
fa = FactorAnalysis(n_components=k, random_state=0)

# Check the dimension
# It should be (n_features, n_components)
fa.components_.T.shape

# Check equation
# It should be all True
fa.components_.T @ fa.components_ + np.diag(fa.noise_variance_) == fa.get_covariance()
```

For more detail, please refer to this document https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html#sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.

Comment: thanks jason, but which function should be apply to my stock return matrix, fit, transform or transform_fit?

Comment: Depends on what you gonna do. `fit` is just train the model. `transform` is to do apply dimensionality reduction to X using the trained model. And `transform_fit`, I guess you mean `fit_transform`, it is just a shortcut for `transform(fit(X))`. The results are exactly the same.